# Should the arithmetic mean of a subset of population data be annotated as sample mean?

Tags: mean, terminology, descriptive-statistics, notation

If I have **population data**, and I want to calculate the **arithmetic mean** of a **subset of the population data** (e.g. for a certain category of values within a certain range of $n$ observations), is the result considered to be sample data?

Depending on the answer, the notation for the arithmetic mean of the data subset would differ, although the calculation is the same:

- Population arithmetic mean: $$ \mu = \frac{\Sigma x}{N} $$
- Sample arithmetic mean: $$ \bar{x} = \frac{\Sigma x}{n} $$

Comment: If the subset where, say amongst men, I would just put that in the subscript of the $\bar x$. The idea is to be clear about what group the mean is calculated for

Answer (score 1):

The framing of this question suggests that the data subset being considered is not a random sample, but rather a category within the population. So I would consider this to be the mean of a *subpopulation* or *subgroup*, not a sample mean.